# How long is too long in cellForRowAtIndexPath to cause UITableView scrolling flicker?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

My tableView's cellForRowAtIndexPath is taking ~20-25ms at times, although typically closer to ~15, and this is causing issues.

35% of that is coming from dequeuing the cell.

60% of it is coming from calling [cell layoutIfNeeded] (which is the only solution that has worked for me with the bug/glitch in iOS8 for Self Sizing Table View Cells [more here: http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2014/08/07/self-sizing-table-view-cells.html]).

Is this a ton of time in terms of screen flicker?

When I scroll the table view, it can often get a tad jumpy. I'm wondering if this has to do with the amount of time the data is taking to lay itself out, or if this is more likely an auto layout issue I need to correct.

Any ideas out there if 20-25ms is an inordinate amount of time, or is that well under the radar?

Comment: Do you execute something on the main thread in parallel with this?

Comment: Well 60fps means you need to render a frame every ~16ms to not drop any frames, so if setting up a single cell takes up more than that not even counting anything else that needs to be handled each frame then you aren't going to get smooth scrolling.